# Why is a shift required to access array position?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I am analysing the following ARM assembly in VIsUAL emulator, a simple function that cycles through an array of constants and chooses the biggest number.

```
    mov     r0, r13            ; pass the memory address where you stored the array's contents
    mov     r1, #20       ; pass the second argument count to the function

    mov     r5, #04               
    mov     r6, #01               
    mov     r7, #13               
    mov     r8, #42               
    mov     r9, #25               
    stmfa   r13, {r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}  
    bl      max
    end
max
    mov     r2, #0
L2
    cmp     r2, r1
    bge     L5
    ldr     r12, [r0, r2, lsl #2]
    add     r2, r2, #1
    cmp     r3, r12
    movlt   r3, r12
    b       L2
L5
    mov     r0, r3
```

It works as intended but one thing I don't understand is in:

```
ldr     r12, [r0, r2, lsl #2]
```

It is loading into r12 the the current value of the array, whose start is pointed by r0 in the current index r2, but why is there a left logical shift there?

Comment: Because words are 4 bytes, so you need to scale by 4, which happens to be a left shift of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done to account for the size of the elements in the array.
In this case it looks like the code is accessing elements 4 bytes in size, potentially an `int` in C (on an ILP32 system, for example).

The loop counter in r2 is incremented by 1 in each iteration of the loop, but each element in the array is 4 bytes away from the previous element, so, assuming that the start of the array is in r0, you want your access pattern to be `[r0 + 0], [r0 + 4], [r0 + 8]...` rather than `[r0 + 0], [r0 + 1], [r0 + 2]...`, which is why a scaling factor of 4 is required.

Comment: Yes, all the standard ABIs for 32-bit ARM are ILP32, so this could also be an array of `long` (but probably not pointers based on the operation being done on them).